# How to collectively disable context menus only for links in HTML

Tags: html, contextmenu

I understand that I can disable all context menus on a HTML page by adding the following:

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false;"></body>
```

However, this will disable all the context menus. I am only interested in disabling the context menus for links. I still want to be able to view the page source, change the encoding, etc, by using the page's context menu. At the same time, I don't want to do this for all the links since I have many links on my page.

```
<a href="foo.html" oncontextmenu="return false;">Foo</a>
```

Therefore, I was wondering if there's a way to collectively disable context menus for all the links on a page without having to add the oncontextmenu attribute to all the links? Perhaps via CSS or other means?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind including jQuery on the page, you can do that with just a few lines:

```
$(function() {
    $('a').attr('oncontextmenu', 'return false;');
});
```

Here's a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vfVpW/)** to demonstrate. You'll probably want to refine the selector of `a` to be more specific, as this jQuery disables context menu for all links in the document.